# 1970s Young Adult fantasy where a girl is transported back in time to England

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I'm looking for book Young Adult fantasy from 70s.

A girl is transported back in time to England. She can stay there as long as she doesn't fall asleep. She is in a boarding school. She manages to stay back in time by sleeping with a hairbrush under her back so when she rolls over, it wakes her up.

Comment: To which time period is she transported? Was it the First World War or thereabouts, by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

"Charlotte Sometimes" (1969) by Penelope Farmer. She puts the hairbrushes by her head to stay awake.
" I had hairbrushes by my head, though, and they woke me up all right."